# C++/CX Delegate in base constructor fails with pure virtual call assertion

Tags: c++, delegates, windows-runtime, c++-cx, pure-virtual

I can't understand why the following code fails with a purvirt call and calls `abort();`

> This is a WinRT project using C++/CX

```
namespace Test {
    public delegate void TickHandle();

    ref class Clock {
    public:
        event TickHandle^ Tick;
    };


    ref class Base {
    internal:
        Base() :
            m_clock(ref new Clock())
        {
            std::cout << "Base::Base" << std::endl;
            m_clock->Tick += ref new Test::TickHandle(this, &Test::Base::OnTick);
            OnTick();
        }
    protected:
        virtual void Foo() = 0;

    private:
        Clock^ m_clock;

        void OnTick()
        {
            std::cout << "Tick" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    ref class Derive : public Base{
    internal:
        Derive() 
        {
            std::cout << "Derive::Derive" << std::endl;
        }
    protected:
        void Foo() override
        {
            std::cout << "Derive::Foo" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    void main()
    {
        auto y = ref new Test::Derive();
    }
}
```

The registration to the `Tick` event is the faulting line which for some reason is considered as a pure virtual call to I-don't-know-what.

I played around with this example and noticed a few things:

1. This only happens if the Base class is pure virtual (notice the
   `Foo() = 0`)
2. It doesn't matter if `Base::Tick` is private \ public \ protected
   etc...
3. I can (obviously) call `OnTick()` from `Base` constructor and it works

Anyone got an explanation?

Comment: Bit of a slog to get this code going.  QueryInterface fails.  C++ rule demands that the v-table points to non-virtual functions while the constructor runs.  The C++ compiler, somehow, knows to work around that rule when the class has no pure functions, not very clear why that trick doesn't work in an abstract base class.  A workaround is to move the event assignment into another function that you call after constructing the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/CX is just a compiler wrapper to make [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) objects easy. This means objects implementing [IUnknown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx). In the constructor of `Base`, the virtual function table for `IUnknown` has yet to be initialized, so all entrys are "pure virtual". When you attempt to register the tick handler, it wants to add a reference to `this` by calling `IUnknown::AddRef` which until the object is fully constructed still points to the "pure virtual" implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that the ref count might be the case but did not think of the IUnknown part. I still dont get something- in the constructor body of Base, `this` is already a strong ref to Base isn't it? So then I would think that the base of Base (IUnknown) was initialized, if so then why is it not constructed when I try to register to the Tick event?

Comment: You cannot implement `IUnknown` until you know what the final type is. I assume that `ref new` wraps `Derived` in one final template so that it can implement `IUnknown` correctly. Until then `IUnknown` is pure. Because you are constructing an object, you know `this` is good, but there still isn't a COM reference being held yet, since until the most derived type is fully constructed, this is a true com object.